# How to check if a function/method/class is built-in Python?

Tags: python

If I do something like this :

```
from mailbox import Mailbox
Mailbox.get = 'dummy'
```

There is no error, I just replaced the `get` method.
But if I do a :

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime.now = 'dummy'
```

I get :

```
TypeError: can't set attributes of built-in/extension type 'datetime.datetime'
```

This is strange because the source code is readable at `/usr/lib/python3.6/datetime.py`.
I guess this library has been compiled for performance reason, that is why it cannot be modified. But, then, the question is : how I can know a class is immutable because it is built-in or an extension (without just testing like I did) ? why can I patch `Mailbox` class and not `datetime` class ?

Comment: you cannot change the value of ```datetime.now```

Comment: ```datetime.now``` is a immutable attribute of the ```datetime``` class. is your question how to tell if something is immutable or "how to check if a function/method/class/ is built-in Python"?

Comment: At the bottom of `datetime.py`, there is an attempt to import names from `_datetime`, replacing anything defined in pure Python earlier in the module. But Python itself doesn't necessarily distinguish between pure Python classes and extensions.

Comment: You might want to adjust your title- it does not match your actual question, which appears to be about setting attributes

Comment: [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It won't tell you directly, but for your case, you can test the method you're trying to replace to see if it's an instance of [`types.BuiltinMethodType`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.BuiltinMethodType):

```
>>> isinstance(Mailbox.get, types.BuiltinMethodType)
False
>>> isinstance(datetime.now, types.BuiltinMethodType)
True
```

[`inspect.isbuiltin`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.isbuiltin) provides the same info:

```
>>> inspect.isbuiltin(Mailbox.get)
False
>>> inspect.isbuiltin(datetime.now)
True
```

To be clear, this is a limitation of the CPython reference interpreter; nothing requires attributes/methods of built-in types to be immutable, and in other interpreters (e.g. PyPy) they may be mutable.

Comment: @Ronald: Yes. Or `import inspect` if you use the other approach.

Answer (score 0):

Simple, import the module of interest, and reference it:

```
>>> import math
>>> math
<module 'math' (built-in)>
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy
<module 'numpy' from 'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\lib\\site-packages\\numpy\\__init__.py'>
```

As you can see, `math` is built-in, while `numpy` is not.

Comment: This will be misleading for most effectively built-in modules though. For example, the OP's case of `datetime` is a module that is not built-in, but it replaces most of its innards with stuff from `_datetime` (which is built-in).